# 'argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable' exception when trying to parse website links with Python + BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
DOMAIN = 'https://www.vgmusic.com/'
URL= 'https://www.vgmusic.com/music/console/nintendo/snes/'
FILETYPE= '.mid'

def get_soup(url):
    return BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

for i in get_soup(URL).find_all('a'):
    mid_link=i.get('href')
    if FILETYPE in mid_link:
        print(mid_link)
```

Here I am attempting to read all the contents of some websites and print out filenames of all linked files with a given extension. Sadly, the above script does not work, at all. In the second to last line, the TypeError exception happens, for a reason that completely eludes me. I am obviously doing something wrong, can't truly understand what.
I can see there is a connection to this website: [references the first link to the .mid file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HzIn.png)

So:
adding `href` to the string in line 11 doesn't cause the script to crash, but also doesn't print anything. Based on some research and advice I could find, I made another, even uglier version of a parser:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
url="https://www.vgmusic.com/music/console/nintendo/snes/"
FILETYPE= ".mid"

soup = bs (urlopen(url))
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        mid_link=link.get('href')
        ##if FILETYPE not in mid_link:
                ##continue
        ##else: 
        print (mid_link)
```

This one works but prints out absolutely all links, disregarding if it links to the file or a Disqus comment section. Uncommenting the if statement = TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable, which gets me to point 0.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one `<a>` element in the document that does not have an `href` attribute, therefore `link.get('href')` returned None.

This is an example of such an element:

```
<a name="4_Nin_Shogi_Japan">
```

The code should verify that the link actually has an `href` attribute before it checks for filetype.

You can do this with an extra condition in the if statement:

```
if mid_link and FILETYPE not in mid_link:
```

Or by providing a default value to be returned by `.get()` if the attribute is not found:

```
mid_link=link.get('href', '')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was a dumb oversight on my side...